# Filtering multiple models in Django

Tags: python, json, django, model

I want to Filter across multiple tables in Django.

```
    q = json.loads(request.body)
    qs = Search.objects.filter(keyword__icontains=q['q']).all()
    data = serialize("json", qs, fields=('keyword', 'user'))
```

That's one,
secondly, the user field is returning an integer value (pk) instead of maybe the username.

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting 'user__username' instead of 'user'. It might work.

Comment: You know, its a OneToOneField with the Search Model, so its defined as 'user'
So basically i'm using user to reference the actual User Model